# Whitespace characters affects returned size of input from scanf

Tags: c, size, whitespace, scanf

I'm using this code to catch user's standart input and then print it back with number of characters saved.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[100];
    int inputSize;
    while (scanf("%99s%n", input, &inputSize) != EOF)
    {
        printf("INPUT: %s, SIZE %d\n", input, inputSize);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And these are results:

```
> hello
INPUT: hello, SIZE: 5
> hello
INPUT: hello, SIZE: 6
```

Why is the size not the same?
How can I get exact size every time?

And finally:
The char variable is array, right?
Then why this does NOT happen?

```
> AAAAAAAAAA
INPUT: AAAAAAAAAA, SIZE: 10
> BBBBB
INPUT: BBBBBAAAAA, SIZE: 6
```

What happened to saved 10x A? They are deleted on new input? Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you write into the same array twice without specifying at which place to start, you are going to overwrite stuff, naturally.

Comment: Yeah, but with BBBBB I'm only overwriting first 5 characters in array, so another AAAAA on the end should remain untouched.

Comment: Was the "AAAAAAAAAA" input a continuation of the "Hello" "Hello" or a new run of the program?

Comment: What  entered after "BBBBB"? The <Enter> key? A <Ctrl-D>?

Comment: Is `INPUT: BBBBBAAAAA, SIZE: 6` a correct transcription of what happened?  Was it `INPUT: BBBBB, SIZE: 6` instead?

Comment: @chux: no, it was just example of new imput. Enter. No, I just asked why it showed only 5 B and not 5 B and 5 A.

Comment: Hope it is clear: the result is `INPUT: BBBBB, SIZE: 6`  because `scanf("%99s...` 1) reads `"\nBBBBB\n"` 2) Discards leading `'\n'`, 3) Saves `"BBBBB"` into `input` - that is **6** `char` total 4) appends a null character 5) puts 2nd `'\n'` back into `stdin`.  `printf("%s", input)` would print only up to the null character.  `'A'` likely exist after the null character - but that is after the string's end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the size not the same?

User input is "hello\nhello\n".

The first `scanf("%99s%n", input, &inputSize)` scans `"hello\n"`.  Sees `'\n`' as trailing white-space, puts it back into `stdin`.  So **5** `char` are scanned, saving 5 `char` in `input`.  Then it appends a `'\0'` to `input`.

The next `scanf("%99s%n", input, &inputSize)` scans `"\nhello\n"`.  `"%s"` scans but does not save leading white-space.  Sees 2nd `'\n`' as trailing white-space, puts it back into `stdin`.  So **6** `char` are scanned, saving 5 `char` in `input`.  Then it appends a `'\0'` to `input`.

> How can I get exact size every time?

Enter the same thing - type <kbd>Enter</kbd> before the first "Hello".  `"%s"` ends its scanning *before* the end-of-line.  The real solution it to not use `scanf()`.  If user input is *line* orientated, use `fgets()` or `getline()` and then parse as needed.

> ... The char variable is array, right? Then why this does NOT happen?

It *is* happening.  `input` is an array 10 of `char`.   This is certainly a new run of the program and so `n` of 10 matches the `char` save in `input` as there was no preceding `'\n'` to discard.

```
> AAAAAAAAAA
INPUT: AAAAAAAAAA, SIZE: 10
```

> What happened to saved 10x A? They are deleted on new input? Why?

The `A` saved in `input` are overwritten with the `B`s.

It remains a mystery why the last output is `"BBBBBAAAAA"` and not `"BBBBB"`.  Given "SIZE: 6", suspect OP transcription error.

Comment: "*Then why this does **NOT** happen?*" -- The OP mentions "*NOT*" which indicates that the output that the OP gets is different from the expected output.

Comment: @Cool Guy Post is unclear on "this".  The second case is certainly a re-run of code and "it" **does** happen: The first `"AAAAAAAAAA"` --> `SIZE 10`.  OP evidently enters `BBBBB` and gets `SIZE: 6` rather than the expected 5 for the same answered reason with "Hello" "Hello".  Note: OP's reporting of `BBBBBAAAAA` instead of `BBBBB` is dubious.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%99s%n", input, &inputSize)
```

Will write the x char read on the x first bytes of "input".
You can try

```
scanf("%99s%n", &input[TotalAmountOfBytesRead], &inputSize)
```

Then, it will give to scanf the adress of the first byte not already written.
Beware of buffer overflow though (Hint: malloc()/realloc()).